# How to write an unit test in Jest to check for variable reassignment?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jasmine, jestjs

I am using Jest to test a helper function in my React application. Following is my test module:

```
import React from 'react';
import returnFirstTwoDrivers from '../../../src/Utils/returnFirstTwoDrivers';

describe('returnFirstTwoDrivers()', function () {
  it('should be assigned to a constant', function () {
     expect(function () { 
       returnFirstTwoDrivers = 'testing reassignment';
       throw new TypeError();
   }).toThrow(TypeError);
 });
```

Here, I am reassigning the `returnFirstTwoDrivers` variable and I am expecting this operation to throw an error because `returnFirstTwoDrivers` is a `const` variable.

When I run the test, the test suite fails to run and it is showing an error on line: `returnFirstTwoDrivers = 'testing reassignment';` If anyone know how to fix this issue, please help me. Thank you.

Comment: What are you actually trying to test here? This is a language-level error, not a runtime error.

Comment: If i get you right then you basically check wether a const could be reassigned. But that is a language feature and you dont have to test it.

Comment: @DaveNewton I am trying to check whether I can reassign ```returnFirstTwoDrivers```

Comment: @socrates Obviously you cannot--but this is a compile-time error, not a runtime error. This makes no sense to test.

Comment: yeah, I know. How do I check it? I do not want ```returnFirstTwoDrivers``` to be assigned to a ```let``` or ```var```

Comment: @socrates You're not understanding what we're saying. JS-the-language will not let you execute this code, because it's a compile-time error, a language-level feature. Testing this is non-sensical.

Comment: @socrates And it isn't. `imports` are `const` and may not be re-assigned. You cannot enforce how people will use your code, though, e.g., if they use `require` with a `var` or `let`, neither you nor the compiler can complain.